# RestKit 0.20: Map relational data from local file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

I'm taking a local JSON file and trying to map it into a relational mapping. It works fine without the relationship, but once I add the relationship, I get an error.

**JSON:**

https://gist.github.com/4675414

**Code:**

```
    // Get json from destination
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:contentPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSString* MIMEType = @"application/json";
    NSError* parseError;

    NSData *data = [myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:MIMEType error:&parseError];
    if (parsedData == nil && parseError) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot parse data: %@", parseError);
    }

    // Setting up objectmapping for issue
    RKObjectMapping *issueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Issue class]];
    [issueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"title":                      @"title",
     @"description":                @"description",
     @"cover_url":                  @"cover_url",
     @"published_at":               @"published_at",
     @"issue_number":               @"issue_number"
     }];

    //Setting up objectmapping for article
    RKObjectMapping *articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
    [articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"title":                      @"title",
     @"main_text":                  @"main_text",
     @"article_image_url":          @"article_image_url"
     }];
    [issueMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"articles" toKeyPath:@"articles" withMapping:articleMapping]];

    Issue *issue = [[Issue alloc] init];
    RKMappingOperation* mapper = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:[parsedData objectForKey:@"issue"] destinationObject:issue mapping:issueMapping];
    RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource new];
    mapper.dataSource = mappingDS;
    [mapper performMapping:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"Parse error: %@", parseError);
    NSLog(@"Issue title: %@", issue.title);
```

**Error:**

```
    2013-01-30 13:07:42.486 uninkd[13722:907] *** Assertion failure in -[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource mappingOperation:targetObjectForRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:], /Users/holgersindbaek/Projects/Uninkd/Uninkd_IOS/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:232

    2013-01-30 13:07:42.487 uninkd[13722:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource must be initialized with a managed object context.'
```

**Error if I take away the data source:**

```
    2013-01-30 13:27:32.601 uninkd[13754:907] *** Assertion failure in -[RKMappingOperation applyRelationshipMappings], /Users/holgersindbaek/Projects/Uninkd/Uninkd_IOS/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMappingOperation.m:699
    2013-01-30 13:27:32.603 uninkd[13754:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot perform relationship mapping without a data source'
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource` is expecting a managed object context, this is specifically for Core Data. Are you using core data?

Forget everything I previously said and use:

```
#import "RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource.h"
RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource new];
mapper.dataSource = mappingDS;
```

instead of:

```
RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource new];
mapper.dataSource = mappingDS;
```

A hint, don't use any classes that say `ManagedObject` if you're not using CoreData. This is referring to a `ManagedObject` in a `ManagedObjectContext` which is unique to CoreData. That being said, core data + restkit is awesome and you should check it out.

Comment: No. I'm not using core data. For now I just want to map the json and then do something with it afterwards. Am I taking a wrong approach? Thank you for the quick answer btw.

Comment: What if you just remove the `mapper.dataSource = mappingDS;`

Comment: That's what I started off with. Then I get the error above (just updated question).

Comment: Hold on, I think you should be doing it differently...let me edit my post.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'm not sure what to put as ##NSURLRequest## and what to use for @"url/path/to/api". I'm using a local json file (json file from a directory). So I have the path to the file, but that's about it. I've updated the question above with the new code.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk sorry I forgot you said local

Comment: No problem. Do you have a suggestion for when you are dealing with a local file?

Comment: @ mkral No, it didn't. Actually already tried it. It tells me that i RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource is an unknown type name and suggests that I replace it with RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk hmm... this post says otherwise. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restkit/Apwt5v4VHtk but you're right I don't see that class either.

Comment: try importing that class #import "RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource.h"

Comment: BEAUTIFUL :-). Now it works perfectly. Very weird that I have to import that though. Is that a bug?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk I'd guess that this isn't the intended way to create the MappingRequest. It's not documented in the docs. You may want to look into other ways how to do so. If I come across anything else I'll update the answer

Comment: I think it is though. They give an example at the bottom of this page - https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0 - doing it exactly that way.